# Changes in JavaScript file is loaded correctly but the behaviour on the page isn't changed

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I have had this issue a few times before and have no idea why it happens. When I go back to an old JavaScript file that I haven't edited for a while and try to make some change, it is changed in Inspect after a hard refresh but the behaviour isn't changed on the page.

For simplicity I try to add a `alert("test")` at the top of the function which runs when I click a button. After purging/emptying cache and doing a hard refresh I can open the file via Inspector and see the `alert("test")` on top of the function. But when I click the button, it just runs the rest of the code as normal and skips my added code.

**What I tried**

- Clearing cache
- Doing hard refresh in Inspect and with Ctrl + F5
- Closing browser and re-open it
- Going in incognito mode

Nothing helps!

**What works**

If I rename the onclick function to `function2` and also change the function name to `function2` in the JS file, THEN the new behaviour is accepted and I see the alert.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

**Extra information**

I am on Windows 10 and it is the same for all browsers I try. I tried Chrome, Edge and Firefox, all with hard reloads and incognito mode but same outcome on all machines. Normally I can update JS files but this seems to be happening for files I have not edited for a long time. I use WordPress too if that is of any help.

Comment: Closed for missing clarity? What is not clear with the question?? It seems impossible to ask ANYTHING on SO these days......

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of times and was also quite puzzled. It might just be some browser problem. I guess the question was closed because it is almost impossible to figure out what is going on in your specific environment and you might try to add some information about your specific browser etc. I will vote to reopen it but …

Comment: @doberkofler, thanks! It is any browser, but I can add a bit more information. It seems impossible to me too, hence why I Asked a quesiton about it lol